# Php/laravel "link_to_route" to JQuery <a> tag

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-4

I have this in Laravel

```
  {{ link_to_route('users.publications.create', 'text of link', ['users' => $user->username]) }}
```

What it does is create a "< a >" HTML tag to a view in the site link this:

```
<a href="http://kinbu.co/users/luis02lopez/publications/create >text of link</a>
```

I want to have the same result in JQuery but it uses the "users" in the link route as other user:

```
            var action_call = $({{ link_to_route('users.publications.create', 'publica uno como intercambio',
            ['users' => $user->username], ['style' => 'color:blueviolet']) }}
            });
            body.append(action_call);
```

With which I have the next error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rddxC.jpg

Do I need to create other `var` with the users name?

If any idea will be a great help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A solution for get the logged (and principal) user information is:

```
Auth::user()->username
```

This bring the data of the logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

Below You Needed:

```
<a href="http://kinbu.co/users/luis02lopez/publications/create >text of link</a>
```

I have better suggestion for it

```
<a href="/users/{username}/publications/create >text of link</a>
```

Don't use site **NAME or URL** references just pass `/` the url and replace `{username}` with your desire variable and it's work